# Showing a list of friends progessively using ajax and the "View More" button

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, jquery

I have a controller that returns a list of friends (over 100 friends). 
I want to display the first ten friends and if I click on a button (*View More* / *Display all*).

How can I do this?
Can Ajax or jQuery do this? (I have never used either.)

Comment: if you are already getting list of all the friends then showing only 10 at a time does not makes a sense. rather write a controller that takes a parameter like `page_number` and returns you list of 10 friends that will come under that page.

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot  can you give me an example thank you, I use a template to show friends what I want is to do like facebook each time displaying more friends

Answer (score 0):

You can look into using MVC's WebGrid. It has built in paging and sorting (also with Ajax support)

Comment: Maybe this is a start http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342578/razor-webgrid-ajax-paging-and-sorting

Comment: thanks, I use a template to show friends
what I want is to do like facebook
each time displaying more friends