# MVC3 razor Webgrid paging and sorting with more than 2000 records

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sorting, razor, paging, webgrid

I am using a webgrid similar to the one mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342578/razor-webgrid-ajax-paging-and-sorting)

```
@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(canPage: true, rowsPerPage: ThisController.PageSize, canSort: true, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "grid");
    grid.Bind(Model.Employees, rowCount: Model.TotalRecords, autoSortAndPage: false);
    grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.All);
    @grid.GetHtml(htmlAttributes: new { id="grid" },
        columns: grid.Columns(
            grid.Column(format: (item) => Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { EmployeeID = item.EmployeeID })),
            grid.Column("FullName"),
            grid.Column("Title")
        ));
}
```

But in my case I am expecting more than 2000 records ,I want to load only 50 records to be loaded on each page,so that the page will load faster. How can I ensure that only first 50 records are loaded when the page gets loaded.and when my user clicks page2 I want to load the next 50 set of records and so on.
Any of you faced anything similar,please suggest me with some sample code

Answer (score 5):

This MSDN Magazine article shows what you want:

[Get the Most out of WebGrid in ASP.NET MVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh288075.aspx)

Read this section: Adding Paging and Sort

> As you can see, the data we’re passing contains the full list of
>   products (295 of them in this example, but it’s not hard to imagine
>   scenarios with even more data being retrieved). As the amount of data
>   returned increases, you place more and more load on your services and
>   databases, while still rendering the same single page of data. But
>   there’s a better approach: server-side paging. In this case, you pull
>   back only the data needed to display the current page (for instance,
>   only five rows).

Comment: Good answer.  The only think I would add is you'll end up needed two database queries.  One to get the paged data (so the 5 rows in this example), plus a query to get the total count of rows to setup the paging correctly.

Answer (score 0):

See this link, it discusses the very same issue of paging in webgrid with large amount of data and an awesome solution to it.

[Efficient Paging with WebGrid Web Helper](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=618)

Hope this helps !

Answer (score -1):

@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(canPage: true, **rowsPerPage: 50**, canSort: true, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "grid");

-remaining code is same as your code

}

just change **rowsperpage:** to the number of rows u want to display

Comment: The WebGrid still loads the whole dataset into memory.

Answer (score -2):

```
List<WebGridColumn> webGridColumn=new List<WebGridColumn>();
var grid=new WebGrid(source:model,
defaultSort:"stk_code",
rowsPerPage:Model.Count(),
canPage:true,
canSort:true);
webGridColumn.Add(grid.Column("stcode",header:"Stock Code",canSort:false));
```