# Client side sorting on ASP.NET MVC WebGrid

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a partial view which contain an MVC WebGrid as below

```
 <div id="grid">
            @{
                var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model.Items,
                                       defaultSort: "Name", 
                                       rowsPerPage: 100);


            }
            @grid.GetHtml(columns: grid.Columns(
                        grid.Column(columnName: "Name", header: "Name", canSort:true),
                        grid.Column(columnName: "Code", header: "Code")
                    ))
            </div>
```

This partial view is loaded using Jquery ajax call and result is inserted into a DIV in the main page.

The table render fine but my problem is that the sorting always generates a callback to the server. I want the sorting to happen at the client side only. Is it possible using WebGrid without using external datatables like jQuery datatable?

Thanks in advance

Comment: see this.. [Razor webgrid ajax paging and sorting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342578/razor-webgrid-ajax-paging-and-sorting)

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I dont want to do an AJAX sorting as well.. I want the complete sorting to happen in Javascript

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you please post the reply as "Answer" so that I can give you credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably implement Cline-Side Sorting by yourself according to the loaded table take a look [here...](http://www.satya-weblog.com/2007/06/client-side-table-sorting-using.html)

NOTE!: you could always make it more generic by using html attributes to tag your WebGrid.
Tag the table with 'data-clineSideSort=true' then add a jquery event that will attach the JS functionality to all such tables holding this property...

```
 function SortTable(sortOn)
 {
     var table = document.getElementById('results');
     var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
     var rows = tbody.getElementsByTagName('tr');

     var rowArray = new Array();
     for (var i = 0, length = rows.length; i < length; i++)
     {
         rowArray[i] = new Object;
         rowArray[i].oldIndex = i;
         rowArray[i].value = rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[sortOn].firstChild.nodeValue;
     }

     if (sortOn == sortedOn)         {
         rowArray.reverse();
     }
     else         {
         sortedOn = sortOn;
         /*
    Decide which function to use from the three:RowCompareNumbers,
    RowCompareDollars or RowCompare (default).
    For first column, I needed numeric comparison.
    */
         if (sortedOn == 0)             {
             rowArray.sort(RowCompareNumbers);
         }
         else             {
             rowArray.sort(RowCompare);
         }
     }

     var newTbody = document.createElement('tbody');
     for (var i = 0, length = rowArray.length; i < length; i++)
     {
         newTbody.appendChild(rows[rowArray[i].oldIndex].cloneNode(true));
     }

     table.replaceChild(newTbody, tbody);
 }

 function RowCompare(a, b)
 {
     var aVal = a.value;
     var bVal = b.value;
     return (aVal == bVal ? 0 : (aVal > bVal ? 1 : -1));
 }

 // Compare number
 function RowCompareNumbers(a, b)
 {
     var aVal = parseInt(a.value);
     var bVal = parseInt(b.value);
     return (aVal - bVal);
 }

 // compare currency
 function RowCompareDollars(a, b)
 {
     var aVal = parseFloat(a.value.substr(1));
     var bVal = parseFloat(b.value.substr(1));
     return (aVal - bVal);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [jQuery Tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/). It can be applied to any well formed table (ie, has  `thead` and `tbody`elements. The only gotcha I can think of here is to make sure you bind table sorter once the data has been loaded in your ajax call.